# How do I create a multiple regression equation using statsmodels.api and pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm attempting to create a multiple regression equation. The dependent variable is the change in a stock's Open price from last week to this week. The independent variables are [last week's open price divided by that year's minimum open price] and [the Open price from 2 weeks ago to last week].

The data set is large. Here is a snapshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfgFV.png

weekToWeekChange.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

def do_the_thing(data):
    
    for i in range(0, len(data["Open"])):
        if(type(data["Open"][i]) == str):
            data["Open"][i] = data["Open"][i].replace(",", "", 1)
       
    data["weeklyChange"] = ""
    data["weeklyChange"][1] = float(data["Open"][1]) / float(data["Open"][0])
```

MinToValue.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

def do_the_thing(data):

    for i in range(0, len(data["Open"])):
        if(type(data["Open"][i]) == str):
            data["Open"][i] = data["Open"][i].replace(",", "", 1)

    data["minYear"] = ""
    data["percentOfMin"] = ""

    for num in range(52, len(data["Open"])):
        minimum = data["Open"][num]
        for num2 in range(i, num):
            if(data["Open"][num2] < minimum):
                minimum = data["Open"][num2]
        data["minYear"][num] = minimum
        data["percentOfMin"][num] = data["Open"][num] / data["minYear"][num]
```

CombinationWeekChangeMin.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def do_the_thing(data):

    X = data[['weeklyChange', 'percentOfMin']].iloc[52:260]
    y = data['weeklyChange'].iloc[53:261]
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    print(X)
    model = sm.OLS(y, X)
    results = model.fit()
    print(results.summary())
```

AlgoApp3.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import WeekToWeekChange
import MinToValue
import warnings
import CombinationWeekChangeMin
import matplotlib.pyplot

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

METAdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Algo/META.csv')
AAPLdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Algo/AAPL.csv')
AMZNdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Algo/AMZN.csv')
NFLXdata =  pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Algo/NFLX.csv')
GOOGLdata = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Algo/GOOGL.csv')

print("META")
WeekToWeekChange.do_the_thing(METAdata)
MinToValue.do_the_thing(METAdata)
CombinationWeekChangeMin.do_the_thing(METAdata)
print("AAPL")
WeekToWeekChange.do_the_thing(AAPLdata)
MinToValue.do_the_thing(AAPLdata)
print("AMZN")
WeekToWeekChange.do_the_thing(AMZNdata)
MinToValue.do_the_thing(AMZNdata)
print("NFLX")
WeekToWeekChange.do_the_thing(NFLXdata)
MinToValue.do_the_thing(NFLXdata)
print("GOOGL")
WeekToWeekChange.do_the_thing(GOOGLdata)
MinToValue.do_the_thing(GOOGLdata)
```